# Labelfunction in Barseries along with plotseries

Tags: apache-flex, charts, labelfunction

I have a Flec Bar chart. It has a Bar series. I need to show the datalabel at the tip of the bars. For this am using labelFunction.This works fine. Now I want to add a plotseries in the same chart. Once it is added the labelfunction in the bar series is not working. The labels are not visible.Any idea?Thanks

```
<mx:Application  xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">          
  <mx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.charts.series.items.PlotSeriesItem;
    import mx.charts.series.items.BarSeriesItem;
    import mx.charts.ChartItem;
    import mx.controls.Label;   
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;  
    //Dataprovider for chart    
[Bindable]
 private var medalsAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
{ Country: "USA", Gold: 35, Silver:39, Bronze: 29,prevRank:"1",isIncrease:true },
{ Country: "China", Gold: 32, Silver:17, Bronze: 14,prevRank:"2",isIncrease:false }
 ]);
     private function setCustomLabel(element:ChartItem):String {                  
var data:BarSeriesItem = BarSeriesItem(element);      
 return (data.item.prevRank).toString();    
     }
 public function init(element:Object):String {
                    var data:PlotSeriesItem = PlotSeriesItem(element);                      
                    if(data.item.isIncrease){    
                            return "images/increase.png";
                    }
                    else{
                            return "images/decrease.png";         
                    }          
     }
]]></mx:Script>
 <mx:VBox>
<mx:BarChart id="bar" showDataTips="true"
            dataTipMode="multiple" >           
            <mx:verticalAxis>
                    <mx:CategoryAxis id="v1"  categoryField="Country"  dataProvider="{medalsAC}"/>
                </mx:verticalAxis>
                 <mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
                    <mx:AxisRenderer placement="left" axis="{v1}"
                        verticalAxisTitleAlignment="vertical">
                    </mx:AxisRenderer>                 
                </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
            <mx:series>
                <mx:BarSeries id="bs2"
                    yField="Country" 
                    xField="Silver"                    
                   dataProvider="{medalsAC}" labelFunction="setCustomLabel"
                />
              <mx:PlotSeries id="plotSeries" yField="Country" xField="Silver"   dataProvider="{medalsAC}"                   
                    displayName="Current Trend">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
            <mx:Image source="{outerDocument.init(data)}" horizontalAlign="center" height="16" width="16"/>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
             </mx:PlotSeries>
            </mx:series>
        </mx:BarChart>

</mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: <mx:BarChart id="bar"  showDataTips="true"       dataTipMode="multiple" >

Comment: Edit your question to add *all* of the code related to the bar chart.

Comment: Hi, This is fully functional code. You can just copy paste the contents in above 4 comments. Thanks in advance for your prompt repsonse.Appreciate tht!

Comment: Oh jesus.  I said *edit your question*! Don't add code in the comments.  Please delete your comments and add the code to the question itself.

Comment: My apologies. Have edited the question. Did n't know the formats in this forum.

Comment: Any updates? or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<mx:Application  xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">          
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.charts.ChartItem;
            import mx.charts.chartClasses.Series;
            import mx.charts.series.items.BarSeriesItem;
            import mx.charts.series.items.PlotSeriesItem;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Label;  

        //Dataprovider for chart    
        [Bindable]
        private var medalsAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            { Country: "USA", Gold: 35, Silver:39, Bronze: 29,prevRank:"1",isIncrease:true },
            { Country: "China", Gold: 32, Silver:17, Bronze: 14,prevRank:"2",isIncrease:false }
        ]);

        private function setCustomLabel(element:ChartItem, series:Series):String
        {                  
            var data:BarSeriesItem = BarSeriesItem(element);      
            return (data.item.prevRank).toString();    
        }
        public function init(element:Object):String 
        {
            var data:PlotSeriesItem = PlotSeriesItem(element);    
            if(data && data.item)
            {
                if(data.item.isIncrease){    
                    return "images/increase.png";
                }
                else{
                    return "images/decrease.png";         
                }     
            }
            return "";
        }
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:BarChart id="bar" showDataTips="true" dataProvider="{medalsAC}"
                     dataTipMode="multiple" >           
            <mx:verticalAxis>
                <mx:CategoryAxis id="v1"  categoryField="Country"  dataProvider="{medalsAC}"/>
            </mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
                <mx:AxisRenderer placement="left" axis="{v1}"
                                 verticalAxisTitleAlignment="vertical">
                </mx:AxisRenderer>                 
            </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
            <mx:series>
                <mx:BarSeries id="bs2"
                              yField="Country" 
                              xField="Silver"        
                              labelPosition="inside"
                              labelFunction="setCustomLabel"
                              />
                <mx:PlotSeries id="plotSeries" yField="Country" xField="Silver" dataProvider="{medalsAC}"                   
                               displayName="Current Trend">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:Image source="{outerDocument.init(data)}" horizontalAlign="center" height="16" width="16"/>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:PlotSeries>
            </mx:series>
        </mx:BarChart>

    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

However, it must be said that the code is messy and you're using Flex 3 while Flex 4 is already out.  You should create the item renderer in a separate class and always check for null objects because they can (and will) create errors.

Comment: That works. Actually there is not much of difference in this code. The labels still are not visible when the number of bars in the chart increases(say there are 10 bars),in this case the width of each bar is decreased and the labels are not visible.however in the same case, if I do not have plot series but 10 bars, then labels are visible. And yes, agreed that I should have created the itemrenderer in a separate class. Thanks.